# Сравнить истинные и предсказанные значения в машинном обучении

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Прогнозирование заработной платы. Набор данных около 40 000 записей (должность, опыт работы, компания, график и тд).
Оценка R^2 около 35-40%.
Использую регрессоры из sklearn и кроссвалидацию.

```
gb_reg = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0, **params)
gb = cross_validate(gb_reg, X, y, cv=5, scoring=('r2', 
                                             'neg_mean_absolute_error'),
                    return_train_score=True)
```

Можно ли каким-то образом вывести на экран значения столбцов, истинные и предсказанные, чтобы понять в чем конкретно ошибается модель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf = KFold(n_splits=5)

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index], X.loc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    gb_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = gb_reg.predict(X_test)
    # тут вопрос - какая разница предсказания и истинных значений вас интересует?
    diff_mask = (y_pred - y_test).abs() > 1 # подберите интересующую вас разницу
    X_diff = X_test.copy()
    X_diff['y_true'] = y_test
    X_diff['y_pred'] = y_pred
    print(X_diff[diff_mask])
```

Comment: а выходные данные "y" мы получается сюда не передаем? они ведь тоже должны делиться на обучающие и тестовые

Comment: в строке X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index] выдает ошибку
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([ 7546,  7547,  7548,  7549,  7550,  7551,  7552,  7553,  7554,\n             7555,\n            ...\n            37718, 37719, 37720, 37721, 37722, 37723, 37724, 37725, 37726,\n            37727],\n           dtype='int64', length=30182)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: `y` тоже делится, сразу за `X`. Просто в сам `split` его не нужно передавать, там индексы образуются, для их генерации достаточно `X`. А по второму вопросу я поменял код, там `X.loc` надо делать. Но может и ещё где ошибки выйдут, я так, навскидку код писал. Просто чтобы принцип сам показать, куда вам смотреть

Comment: спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: а еще вопрос. с использованием kfold ведь такая же точность должна получаться, как и через cross_validate?

Comment: Примерно да. У вас там `cv=5` параметр стоит, значит такая же 5-фолдовая кросс-валидация. Я только не помню как там итоговая точность считается - усредняется точность за все фолды что ли. Но в общем да, вроде бы должно быть тоже самое.